# If the property P is true for all $x\in A$ and P is true for all $y\in B$, is $P(A \cup B)$ true?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic

Restating my question from the title

> If the property P is true for all $x\in A$ and P is true for all $y\in B$, is $P(A \cup B)$ true?

I argue that the indeed  $P(A \cup B)$ holds, as follows.

For sake of contradiction suppose  $\exists z \in (A\cup B)$, such that $P(z)$ is false. It follows that $z \in A$, $z \in B$ or $z\in (A \cap B)$. In each of these cases $P(z)$ is true by assumption, so we arrive at a contradiction. Therefore $P(A\cup B)$ must be true. This completes my argument.

If anyone would be kind enough to verify my argument or point out any error(s), I would be grateful.

Comment: The only options are $z\in A$ or $z\in B$. The last option $z\in (A\cup B)$ is given in the beginning already. Besides this the argument is correct.

Comment: Sorry, this is supposed to be $A\cap B$

Comment: You don't even need this case. By definition $z\in A\cup B$ if and only if $z\in A$ or $z\in B$ and so these are the only options you need to check. You should note that when mathematicians use "or" they usually means either this or that or both.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose it was a bit of an overkill then...

Comment: You show that $P(z)$ is true for all $z\in A\cup B$. This is not the same as claiming that $P(A\cup B)$ is true (and in general, it is not: Let $P(x)\equiv x\ne x$. Then $P(x)$ is false for all $x$, in particular $P(A\cup B)$ is false, no matter what $A$ and $B$ we pick. However, if $A=B=\emptyset$, then $P(x)$ is true fora ll $x\in A$ and true for all $x\in B$.

Comment: I can see how my argument breaks down. Can it be augmented?. Regardless, is the statement true?

Comment: "If the property $P$ is true for all $x ∈ A$ and $P$ is true for all $y ∈ B$, then $P$ is true for all $z ∈ (A∪B)$". In reality, "or" is enough (instead of "and").

Comment: You are using notation incorrectly (or at least in an uncommon way). $P(A\cup B)$ is not equivalent to $P$ holding for every element of $A\cup B$. $A\cup B$ is a perfectly reasonable set on its own and a predicate can hold for this set independently of whether it holds for its elements. For example, defining $P(S)$ to mean "$S$ is an infinite set" holds for $\mathbb N$ but not for any elements of $\mathbb N$ (for usual definitions of $\mathbb N$), while $P(S)$ defined as "$S\subseteq\mathbb N$" holds for every element of $\mathbb N$ as well as $\mathbb N$ itself (with the same caveat).

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem... I get it now.